# form submit php function return value print in html

Tags: php, html

I have a html form. when i submit the form, it manages to call a function. i want to show the result in the html page. the picture is like this:
**THE HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="uploadForm">
<input name="test" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>

<div id="data"><?php echo $result; ?></div>
```

**PHP CLASS**

```
<?php
class Test{

    public function __construct(){
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $result = $this->myfunction();
        }
    }
        private function myfunction(){
        //some actions
        return "values";
        }
}
```

I am just giving the idea. the class file is different php file and so the html is. the instance of the class is created. how can i show the result "values" in the div id="data" after submitting the form?

Comment: If you don't want to reload the page, you need to read about something called AJAX.

Comment: Use **AJAX** for this.

Comment: to show results use `print_r($_POST);` and if you don't want to reload page use **AJAX** as suggested above.

Answer (score 4):

Using AJAX we can display result in that particular div as follows :

```
$('#submitBtn').click(function(){
   $.post("YourFile.php",{$('#form').serialize()},function(res){
       $('#data').html(res);
   });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Although your approach seems a bit weird, here's a version that should be working:

Your html file:

```
<?php /* Includes here */ ?>
<?php $result = new Test($_POST)->getResult(); ?>
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="uploadForm">
<input name="test" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>

<div id="data"><?php echo $result; ?></div>
```

Your php class:

```
<?php
    class Test{

        private $result = '';

        public function __construct($postData){
            if(isset($data['submit'])){
                $this->result = $this->myfunction();
            }
        }

        private function myfunction($postData){
            //some actions
            return "values";
        }

        public function getResult() {
            return $this->result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve the desired code,you need to use AJAX.

In your js file you need to add

```
$('#form type=[submit]').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();//prevents default form submit.
   $.ajax({    //fetches data from file and inserts it in <div id="data"></div>
     url:'your url here',
     data:{data:$(#form).serialize()},
     success :function(data){
$('#data').html(data);
     }
   }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the file or code

```
 <?php
  class Test{
    public $result;
    public function __construct(){
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $this->result=$this->myfunction();
        }
    }
        private function myfunction(){
        //some actions
        return "values";
        }
} 

if(isset($_POST)){
 $test = new Test();
$result=$test->result;
}
?>
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="uploadForm">
<input name="test" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>   

<div id="data"><?php echo $result; ?></div>
```

Comment: Side note: Afaik, $_POST will always be set, so you don't really need to do the `isset($_POST)`. :-)